# how to control the arrangement of the data in sharedPreferences

Tags: android, kotlin

I will try to do my best to explain the problem and thanks

im using sharedpreferences to save my data as string and to add new data i add it in an array and
the sharedprefrences file (tab is an arrayString)

```
tab.add(textToShow)
customadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
editor.putString(textToShow , textToShow) // Ex : key = "hello" , value = "hello"
editor.apply()
```

but when i get my data when i open the app, the data in sharedpreferences file are note save with the order of the insert ( i insert at the end but it will be in order).

So i need to know how to save my data always at the end without order

this is how i get my data

```
mysharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(fileName , 0 ) // 0 = MODE_PRIVATE
val editor : SharedPreferences.Editor = mysharedpreferences.edit()
/** fin 1**/
/** 2) get all data from the file and put it in mymap **/
val mymap : Map<String , *> = mysharedpreferences.all
/** fin 2**/
/** 3) initialise the table and show data **/
for ( (key , value) in mymap ) {
    tab.add(value.toString())
    customadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    thelistv.adapter = customadapter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how Maps work.  A Map class is unordered, by design.  There is no promise that the data comes out in the order it goes in.  If that's what you need, anything that stores data in a Map in memory will not work.  That includes SharedPreferences.  Instead, you need to serialize it to a file yourself.